# How to apply the Splash Screen so that a black screen isn't initailly shown at app startup?

Tags: splash-screen, gluon-mobile

I am troubleshooting my deployment on Android (not yet tested on iOS also).

I have a simple SplashView class that just centers an image.

```
public class MySplashView extends SplashView {

public MySplashView(String nextView) {

    super(nextView);

    Image image = new Image(MySplashView.class.getResourceAsStream("/my_logo.jpg"));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setFitWidth(AppManager.getInstance().getGlassPane().getWidth() * .75);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageView);

    super.setCenter(stackPane);
}
```

I've tried to declare this SplashView as soon as possible in the Application's workflow.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void init() {

    AppManager.getInstance().addViewFactory(SPLASH_VIEW, () -> new MySplashView("loginView"));
}
```

Before introducing this SplashView, the order I'd see at application start would be:

1. Black Screen
2. Login View

Now I see:

1. Black Screen
2. Splash View
3. Login View

What more/else can I do so to stop showing the User an initial black screen?

Comment: Typically if there is a long black screen before the splash or the home view are shown, it means that you are doing too many things in the init/start methods. Moving those things to a background thread, or to a later time could help. To find out, add some printouts and investigate the app logs.